# How do I hide a formula in a cell linked to a value in another cell, until a value is entered

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a sports bracket that moves a winning and losing teams based on score. However, when I reset all scores to "0", #N/A shows up in the cells. How do I hide #N/A until a value is entered?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`#N/A` means “Not Available”. Excel formulas usually return this in situations where a requested value could not be found for some reason.

A common cause of this error code is the VLOOKUP function,
when it can't find a matching value.

The
[IFERROR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)
allows you to specify what should be returned if an error occurs.

As example, to replace missing prices with zero, use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6,$F$2:$G$4,2,FALSE),0)
```

Surrounding any formula with IFERROR lets you choose what will happen
if an error is returned.
Instead of the `0` returned by the previous example, you equally
display "Price Missing" with this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6,$F$2:$G$4,2,FALSE),"Price Missing")
```

See also:
[How to use the Excel IFERROR function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-iferror-function).